# How would i get all documents form a mongodb database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a class that includes helper methods for my MongoDB Connection, including connect, findDocuments and insertDocument.

```js
async findDocuments(collection, query) {
        var response = await this.database.collection(collection).find(query).toArray();
        return response;
}

console.log(mongo.findDocuments('users', {}));
```

I expected to get a list of all the users in my database.
I am receiving a Promise.

Comment: async functions always returns a promise

Comment: And if you `await` that promise, you get the real results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions always return a promise. To see the promise information, you either need to `await` the result if you are in a function, or use a `then()` if you are in the global scope.

Your code looks like it is in the global scope so you will need to use a then:

```
class Mongo {
  async findDocuments(collection, query) {
    var response = (await this.database.collection(collection).find(query)).toArray();
    return response;
  }
}

let mongo = new Mongo();

mongo.findDocuments('users', {}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: @ggorlen you need to `await` the find, I have wrapped that in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns a cursor not a promise so you're calling it correctly. You're getting a promise because you're not awaiting the call to findDocuments.

```
...
async findDocuments(collection, query) {
        var response = await this.database.collection(collection).find(query).toArray();
        return response;
}
...

// await here
console.log(await mongo.findDocuments('users', {}));
```

This is assuming you're calling this inside an async function as well.

#### Node driver reference:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find